# Issue when test "Singleton with new and delete (C++)"

Tags: c++, singleton, new-operator, delete-operator

I have read this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B)) about new and delete in C++. There is a code that implemented Singleton pattern. I have tested this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Singleton {
    static Singleton *instance;
    static std::size_t refcount;
    std::string _s;

  public:
    void setS(std::string s) { _s = s; }
    std::string getS() { return _s; }
    static void *operator new(std::size_t nbytes) throw (std::bad_alloc) {
        std::cout << "operator new" << std::endl;
        if (instance == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "operator new nullptr" << std::endl;
            instance = ::new Singleton; // Use the default allocator
        }
        refcount++;
        return instance;
    }

    static void operator delete(void *p) {
        std::cout << "operator delete" << std::endl;
        if (--refcount == 0) {
            std::cout << "operator delete" << refcount << std::endl;
            ::delete instance;
            instance = nullptr;
        }
    }
};

Singleton *Singleton::instance = nullptr;
std::size_t Singleton::refcount = 0;

int main() {
  Singleton* s = new Singleton;
  //Singleton* t = new Singleton;
  s->setS("string s");
  std::cout << "s " << s->getS() << std::endl;
  Singleton* t = new Singleton;
  std::cout << "t " << t->getS() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But the result is:

```
operator new
operator new nullptr
s string s
operator new
t
```

Why t didn't print out "string s"? If I change the comment line, t can print out "string s".

Comment: How are stack allocated instances taken into account?

Comment: @user4759923: *s and *t are identically, just one. But there are no operator== for Singleton.   If you define this operator, the result is depend on you.

Comment: @user2672165: stack will not use operator new to allocate the storage that was available. This just call the constructor on the storage was allocated on stack. So the objects on stack are different from the one on heap. There is just one object on heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `new Singleton` will call `operator new` to aquire storage, and then intialize the non-static members of the object using the default constructor.

As `_s` is not static, it will be (re)initialized every time a new `Singleton` is created. So will result in a blank string for `t`.

It is very likely UB to reuse the space for the `_s` member this way.

Comment: the storage is same but the constructor will be called for every new-expression that will (re)initialize every non-static members.